# RSpec error ActionController::UrlGenerationError: when testing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing the specs (with RSpec) for my API controller. When I test the GET request for the index everything works well, it returns the expected body and successful response, however, when I test the GET request for the show action it raises the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"api/v1/contacts"}
```

Here is the code that I have written in my spec file:

```html
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::ContactsController do
  describe "GET #index" do
    context 'with a successful request'  do
      before do
        get :index
      end

      it "returns http success" do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end

      it "JSON body response contains expected recipe attributes" do
        json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
        expect(json_response.keys).to match_array(%w[data included])
      end
    end
    end

  describe "GET #show" do
    context 'with a successful request'  do
      before do
        get :show
      end

      it "returns http success" do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the show route that the command `rails routes` prints
[image]

Can someone help me see what am I missing?
How can I test the GET request for the show action with RSpec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that you are not passing the slug parameter required by your route:

```
get :show, slug: contact.slug
```

But what you actually want here in the first place is a [request spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) and not a controller spec. A request spec sends actual HTTP requests to your application. Controller specs mock out most of the framework and let the bugs march right though - especially routing bugs.

The use of controller specs is discouraged by the the Rails and RSpec teams and should not be used outside of legacy code.

```
# spec/requests/api/v1/contacts_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'API V1 Contacts', type: :request do

  # This can be DRY:ed into a shared context
  let(:json){ JSON.parse(response.body) }
  subject { response }
  
  # This example uses FactoryBot
  # https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot
  let(:contact) { FactoryBot.create(:contact) }

  # but you could also use a fixture
  let(:contact){ contacts[:one] }
  
  # describe the actual API and not how its implemented
  describe "GET '/api/v1/contacts'" do
    before { get api_vi_contacts_path }
    it { is_expected.to be_successful }
    it "has the correct response attributes" do
      expect(json.keys).to match_array(%w[data included])
    end
  end
  
  describe "GET '/api/v1/contacts/:id'" do
    before { get api_vi_contact_path(contact) }
    it { is_expected.to be_successful }
    # @todo write examples about the JSON
  end
end
```